# Call class as function without staticmethod and classmethod and instantiating

Tags: python, function, class

This class unlike function can have initialized internal variables.
The fact that the variables are internal makes it more orderly and that it's initialized more efficiently.

```py
import re
class clean_ship_to:
    pattern_num_int = re.compile(r'[\W\_]+') #  initialized internal variable

    @classmethod
    def clean(cls, ship_to):
        ship_to['num_int'] = cls.pattern_num_int.sub('', ship_to['num_int'])[:35]
        ship_to['contact_name'] = ship_to['contact_name'][:35]
        ship_to['contact_phone'] = ship_to['contact_phone'][:25]
        return ship_to
```

This is callable with `clean_ship_to.clean(ship_to)` and I want `clean_ship_to(ship_to)`

Comment: This is a bit of a contradiction, isn't it. It sounds like you're basically saying, "I want to call a class method without an instance of the class."

Answer (score 0):

```py
class clean_ship_to(dict):
    """
    Clean dict ship_to
    """
    # dict inheritance fix pylint(unsubscriptable-object) alert
    pattern_num_int = re.compile(r'[\W\_]+')

    def __new__(cls, ship_to):
        ship_to['num_int'] = cls.pattern_num_int.sub('', ship_to['num_int'])[:35]
        ship_to['contact_name'] = ship_to['contact_name'][:35]
        ship_to['contact_phone'] = ship_to['contact_phone'][:25]
        return ship_to

>>> clean_ship_to(ship_to)
{...}
```